# simple routing on passing param in playframework

Tags: playframework

I have a route like so

```
GET  /projectinfo/{projectName}     premonitionx.Lists.projectInfo
```

which I use fine on some pages then on one page I have a table which iterates of some projects that you can click on so I have an "a href" like so...

```
<a href="@{Lists.projectInfo(inact.project.name)}">${inact.project.fullPath}</a>
```

This completely bombs in that it can't find the route....how to fix this(and hopefully use just the one route for all my pages to reuse).  I am hoping I don't have to repeat routes cluttering up our routes file.

obviously my controller method is projectInfo(String projectName)

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add `permonitionx.` as your package for your Lists class in the href:

```
@{premonitionx.Lists.projectInfo(inact.project.name)
```

Also, you could do this as well:

```
<a href="/projectinfo/${inact.project.name}">${inact.project.fullPath}</a>
```

Comment: DANG!!!! I KEEP making that mistake....I wish I could just type in the class names and it would find them since I don't name any classes the same within my project(so it should just scan my jar not the other jars for my controllers which would be nice....except for plugins of course)